# How to modify the content of fb:request-form dynamically using Javascript?

Tags: javascript, facebook, fbml, xfbml, fbrequest-form

I would like to customize my request-form content using javascript.
Say i have this in my html...

```
<div id="invite">
<fb:serverfbml style="width: 600px; height: 650px;">
    <script type="text/fbml">
        <fb:request-form 
            action="index.php"
            method="POST"
            invite="true"
            type="MyApp"
            content="Please have a look at my new __DYNAMICNAME_HERE__. 
                <fb:req-choice url='http://apps.facebook.com/myapp/' label='View Now!' />" >

            <div class="clearfix" style="padding-bottom: 10px;">
                <fb:multi-friend-selector condensed="true" style="width: 600px;" />
            </div>
            <fb:request-form-submit /></fb:request-form>
    </script>
</fb:serverfbml></div>
```

I would like to dynamically change _DYNAMICNAME_HERE_ to something else via Javascript.

Here are the things that i've tried.

```
function technique1()
{
   var elem = document.getElementById("invite");
   elem.innerHtml = elem.innerHTML.replace("__DYNAMICNAME_HERE__", "MyName");
   // show div code...

   // result is, the current page get's re-rendered inside the div, instead of the FB controls.
}

function technique2()
{
   // Delete all code inside the div... then construct the content using javascript.

   var elem = document.getElementById("invite");
   elem.innerHtml = text;// text is the div innerHtml code constructed at runtime.

   // run show div code
   // result is nothing shows.
}

function technique3()
{
   // First, we remove all code from the div
   // put them into another php page called invite.php

   var elem = document.getElementById("invite");
   elem.innerHtml = "<iFrame src=\"www.myserver.com/invite.php?name=myname\"></iFrame>";

   // run show div code
   // It works but requires 1 more request to the server.
}
```

Does anyone know a technique that does not involve an extra request to the server (invite.php)? Possibly involving FB.XFBML.Host.addElement, refresh etc...

Btw, i'm using Google's Closure the handle popping up the div.

Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

I also came across the same problem and solved it the way that teepark suggested. 
I could not change the HTML of facebook's tags because they render in an iframe. 
MY page is in www.____.com and the iframe is in www.facebook.com. I can't change the contents in that iframe because of cross domain policies.

Answer (score 0):

it's actually engineered to now allow that kind of manipulation. one thing you can do though is render more than one fb:request-form, most of them in < div >s with style="display: none", then change which one is displayed with javascript.

that's a limited solution as it gives you limited choices that must be determined at render time, but AFAIK you just can't get at the html attributes once it's rendered.